# group clusters of numbers in array

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-computing, python-itertools

I have an array like:

```
A = [1,3,8,9,3,7,2,1,3,9,6,8,3,8,8,1,2]
```

And I want to count the number of "entry clusters" that are `>5`. In this case the result should be `4`, because:

```
[1, 3, (8,9), 3, (7), 2, 1, 3, (9,6,8), 3, (8,8), 1, 2]
```

Given `L` length of the array, I can do:

```
A = [1,3,8,9,3,7,2,1,3,9,6,8,3,8,8,1,2]
A = np.array(A)

for k in range(0,L):
    if A[k]>5:
        print k, A[k]
```

and this gives me all entries greater than `5`. But how could I group every cluster of numbers?

Comment: hint: for a cluster the indices `k` will be consecutive integers. all you need to do is (fort example) walk your list of filtered indices and increment a counter every time the next index is not consecutive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `groupby` function from `itertools`.

```
from itertools import groupby

A = [1,3,8,9,3,7,2,1,3,9,6,8,3,8,8,1,2]
result = [tuple(g) for k, g in groupby(A, lambda x: x > 5) if k]

print(result)
# [(8, 9), (7,), (9, 6, 8), (8, 8)]

print(len(result))
# 4
```

Comment: I think that should be what I was looking for

Comment: @urgeo then you should mark this answer as correct.